Blazor Web Assembly add IMAP Gmail with C# CSS
How do I add IMAP to Blazor Web Assembly and add my Gmail to it to sync my Inbox? I want to Fetch the Mails from the Inbox.
I looked up on Youtube, Google and even asked ChatGPT and Gemini but non of them worked properly. I couldnt get the Mails from my Inbox so I would like to get help with step by step constructions. I would also appreciate codes.
